# Yii profiler get methods names

Tags: php, yii

My goal is know all steps what my app execute. Example:

```
Method1() -> Method2() -> Method3()
```

How can I achieve this ? I logging everythin: my log looks like:

```
    'routes' => [
        [
            'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
            'levels' => 'error, warning, trace, info, profile',
            'categories' => 'system.*',

        ],
```

Bet all still not have methods names in log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve profiling exist issue to increse trace level to:

```
define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);
```

That will allow to get file line numbers where method call. In logs you will some thins like:

```
UserController.php 78 line 'SELECT * FROM `users`'
```